# Change name of declared objects in C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, rename

Hi I'm doing changes to my project and look for a smooth way of changing name of variables, classes and methods and such. I've read somewhere that you can "change all xxx to xxx" in project but I'm having a hard time finding info of how you do it.

Comment: What are you talking about? A class? A method? A variable?

Comment: For example: I have changed a name of some of my methods in code, call it a clean-up, and to rename all references I think there is a way that should do it in one sweep but I can't find info about it and I'm quite new at VS.

Comment: Press F2, it is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a class file with .cs extension then select the file from Solution Explorer > Right Click > Rename

After you rename, it will ask you whether you want to change it even in references like this
[image]

But if you want to rename a method then you can also use the following **refactor** feature:

> Double Click and Select the Method > Right Click > Refactor > Rename

Example in Screenshot:[image]

**Refactor** feature in Visual Studio works for all: classes, methods and variables.

Answer (score 4):

Right click Rename, renames all references and mentions of your function variable etc.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your variable and click Rename.

Then you can change its name, and confirm in the box that has appeared in visual studio.

[See this MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Look at "Resharper" or other Addins that are even smarter. They can find also references in comments or source code that is not directly related.